# More than one value in rel and access using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a check like below and for this i want 2 value. Is this possible to pass more than one value in `rel`. Any help would be nice.

```
<a href="#" rel='.$row['Table_ID']. 's''></a>
```

**js:**

```
// Get current row id.
   var Row_id = $(this).attr('rel');

else if(SelectedTab == 'Drug Seizure')
{
    if(Row_id == 's')
    {

    }

    else
    {
        Table_name = "SOME";
        Column_name = "Some_ID";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use rel for that, rel if for the relation to the document. If you use html5, just use data (which you can use for any element):

```
<div id="example" data-numbers="123" data-othervalue="abc"/>

alert( $('#example').attr('data-numbers') );
alert( $('#example').attr('data-othervalue') );
// Or
alert( $('#example').data('numbers') );
alert( $('#example').data('othervalue') );
```

---

To show you another method:

```
<div id="example" data-mixed="123,abc"/>
var info = $('#example').attr('data-mixed').split(","); // split on comma
alert( info[0] ); // 123
alert( info[1] ); // abc
```

---

If you can't use html5, you can use other attributes, like title, class or ID, and use the same tactic. But those should be treated as exceptions. It also has to be noted that this is clientside. Therefor you can not trust the value. Always check serverside.

Comment: It ok to think about that for a bit ;) But I was working on the edit.

Comment: can i use them in `<a> tags` also right? and not just `div`?